# In Na extraction, is Ca2+ of CaCl2 reduced in addition to Na+ of NaCl in electrolysis

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, metal, electrolysis, extraction

In Na extraction from $\ce{NaCl}$, $\ce{CaCl2}$ is added in electrolysis to lower the melting point of the mixture to about $\pu{750 ^\circ C}$. But doesn't $\ce{Ca^2+}$ cation compete with the $\ce{Na+}$ ion to be reduced at the cathode? If so, since $\ce{Ca^2+}$ is right next to the electrochemical series, should we not have a considerable amount of $\ce{Ca}$ as impurity in the $\ce{Na}$ that we have extracted? Where do the inconsistencies lie?

Comment: Electrochemical series is for *aqueous* solution *only*!

Comment: @Mithoron, Got it, thanks. But in this case, how will one decide which cation will be reduced without the help of the electrochemical series?

Comment: Well, there are data for various solvents and melts, not nearly as commonly found or thorough, though.